# wmic to get the username of a remote computer

Tags: c#, wmic

I'm using C# Winforms and I'm trying to get the user name that currently logged on a speitific computer on the domain. I can achieve it by opening CMD with administrator privileges, and then type this line:

```
wmic.exe /node:(computername or ip address) computersystem get username
```

The result is:

```
UserName
Domain\real-user-name
```

However, I wants to get only the `"real-user-name"`.  How can I get it without substring, via WMIC?

Comment: I'd rather say that it is too good that the domain name is also listed along with the username, since there is a possibility of same username being present in multiple domains (maybe not in your environment). So, I'd rather say you should stick with the substring().

Comment: @Am_I_Helpful Yes you are right. So I guess the only option is using substring.

Comment: You should answer this question so that it'd help future visitors. Good Luck.

Comment: @Am_I_Helpful Thanks. Should I answered it as a new answer or just edit my question?

Comment: @WebR Just post an answer to your question, then mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Am_I_Helpful mentioned in the comments, it is too good and important that the result of the `wmic command` is with a domain name.

Therefore, probably, the only option to get only the username is by using `substring()` method on the wmic command output.